# Detection of similar segments of two signal

Tags: signal-analysis, signal-detection

I have two signals, the first is a reference signal from which I selected a segment.

I'm trying to find which segment of the other signal is the most similar to this selected segment.

I'd be glad to have some ideas.

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  What have you tried? What doesn't work about it?

Comment: I guess you want find cross correlation. Read about it and come back if you have problem, but only after trying something from your side.

Answer (score 1):

You could use correlation between the two signals or a matched filter in which you set the filter coefficients as the samples from the selected segment inverted in time. In matlab it would be something like

```
coef = knownSegment (end:-1:1,:);

minSize = length(other_signal) + length(knownSegment) - 1;
N = 2^nextpow2(minSize);
OUT = ifft(fft(other_signal,N).*fft(coef,N));
```

Then you find the maximum value of variable OUT and at that point in time the two signals are most similar

Comment: wouldn't be possible to use the function `xcorr` instead of the ifft?

Comment: yes, xcorr is equivalent you would have to perform xcorr(other_signal,knownSegment), notice that here you don't have to invert any signal as xcorr automatically does that for you. I didn't suggest xcorr before because it's a built-in matlab function